# On $\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1-z^{j^2})$.

Tags: infinite-product, integer-partitions

Given that $$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty} (1-z^{j^2})$$ is of the form $1+\sum_{d=1}^{\infty} a_{d}z^{c_{d}}$

where $c_{1}<c_{2}<... \in \mathbb{N}, a_{d} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there a constant $B>0$ so that $|a_{d}| \leq B$.

---

Background:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}(1-z^{j}) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}(z^{\frac{k(3k-1)}{2}}+z^{\frac{k(3k+1)}{2}})$$

by the Pentagonal number theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem).

This question has been asked to understand distinct square partitions with odd and even containers.

Comment: I doubt it, though I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Please check my question about the product. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187377/generating-function-of-distinct-way-of-partitioned-square-sums-of-positive-integ.  People shared some values of coeffients. the coefficient for $z^{9911}$ is 19304.  the coefficients  for $j=9500..9509$ are −745, −1969, 295, 9240, −4856, −3624, 2864, −5009, 2438, 5219.   It seems it is not like pentagonal theorem . Seems coeffients go bigger and bigger. I do not know if there is a limit or not. Maybe you can check my question for more details.